# puppet master on CentOS 7 - Gone after reboot

Tags: centos7, puppetmaster

I deployed a Puppet Master and Puppet Agent on two different CentOS machines.

They both used to communicate via ssl but upon restart of Master server, things are gone.

Httpd's conf.d contains puppetmaster.conf, hence I need the httpd service to run.

When it worked, the https://name:8140 showed "The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not ''" meaning it was working.

I'm sure I ran

```
"$sudo chkconfig httpd on
Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable httpd.service'."
```

to make this start on boot.

It used to error out on not having available sockets to listen to, but I solved it by killing the puppet process that was taking up the port.

Here's what I tried with no luck:

```
$sudo service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-03-30 12:39:07 PDT; 2min 13s ago
  Process: 4144 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4155 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           â”œâ”€4155 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4180 PassengerAgent watchdog
           â”œâ”€4186 PassengerAgent server
           â”œâ”€4192 PassengerAgent logger
           â”œâ”€4203 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4204 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4205 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4206 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â””â”€4207 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Mar 30 12:39:07 vaio systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 30 12:39:07 vaio python[4146]: SELinux is preventing /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/support-binar...bility.

                                   *****  Plugin sys_resource (37.5 confidence) suggests   **********************...
Mar 30 12:40:49 vaio systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.


$sudo service httpd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service


(IPtable)
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT


(SELinux Status)
 sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected. 
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted 

(HTTPD status -l)

sudo service httpd status -l
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2015-03-30 12:39:07 PDT; 20min ago
 Main PID: 4155 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           â”œâ”€4155 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4180 PassengerAgent watchdog                                                 
           â”œâ”€4186 PassengerAgent server                                                 
           â”œâ”€4192 PassengerAgent logger                                                 
           â”œâ”€4203 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4204 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4205 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â”œâ”€4206 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           â””â”€4207 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Mar 30 12:39:07 vaio systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 30 12:39:07 vaio python[4146]: SELinux is preventing /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent from using the sys_resource capability.

                               *****  Plugin sys_resource (37.5 confidence) suggests   **********************

                               If you do not want processes to require capabilities to use up all the system resources on your system;
                               Then you need to diagnose why your system is running out of system resources and fix the problem.  

                               According to /usr/include/linux/capability.h, sys_resource is required to:

                               /* Override resource limits. Set resource limits. */
                               /* Override quota limits. */
                               /* Override reserved space on ext2 filesystem */
                               /* Modify data journaling mode on ext3 filesystem (uses journaling
                                  resources) */
                               /* NOTE: ext2 honors fsuid when checking for resource overrides, so
                                  you can override using fsuid too */
                               /* Override size restrictions on IPC message queues */
                               /* Allow more than 64hz interrupts from the real-time clock */
                               /* Override max number of consoles on console allocation */
                               /* Override max number of keymaps */
                               /* Override resource limits. Set resource limits. */
                               /* Override quota limits. */
                               /* Override reserved space on ext2 filesystem */
                               /* Modify data journaling mode on ext3 filesystem (uses journaling
                                  resources) */
                               /* NOTE: ext2 honors fsuid when checking for resource overrides, so
                                  you can override using fsuid too */
                               /* Override size restrictions on IPC message queues */
                               /* Allow more than 64hz interrupts from the real-time clock */
                               /* Override max number of consoles on console allocation */
                               /* Override max number of keymaps */
                               /* Override resource limits. Set resource limits. */
                               /* Override quota limits. */
                               /* Override reserved space on ext2 filesystem */
                               /* Modify data journaling mode on ext3 filesystem (uses journaling
                                  resources) */
                               /* NOTE: ext2 honors fsuid when checking for resource overrides, so
                                  you can override using fsuid too */
                               /* Override size restrictions on IPC message queues */
                               /* Allow more than 64hz interrupts from the real-time clock */
                               /* Override max number of consoles on console allocation */
                               /* Override max number of keymaps */

                               Do
                               fix the cause of the SYS_RESOURCE on your system.

                               *****  Plugin catchall_boolean (30.1 confidence) suggests   ******************

                               If you want to allow httpd to run stickshift
                               Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_run_stickshift' boolean.
                               You can read 'None' man page for more details.
                               Do
                               setsebool -P httpd_run_stickshift 1

                               *****  Plugin catchall_boolean (30.1 confidence) suggests   ******************

                               If you want to allow httpd to setrlimit
                               Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_setrlimit' boolean.
                               You can read 'None' man page for more details.
                               Do
                               setsebool -P httpd_setrlimit 1

                               *****  Plugin catchall (4.20 confidence) suggests   **************************

                               If you believe that PassengerAgent should have the sys_resource capability by default.
                               Then you should report this as a bug.
                               You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
                               Do
                               allow this access for now by executing:
                               # grep PassengerAgent /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
                               # semodule -i mypol.pp

Mar 30 12:40:49 vaio systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 30 12:52:58 vaio systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: The SELinux error there looks suspicious.  Was this working as the puppetmaster service and not the httpd service before?  Does it work correctly if you temporary disable SELinux?

Comment: Only saw it run on httpd service. Let me try disabling SELinux.

Comment: Updated the post with iptable and SELinux status

Comment: Just run `setenforce 0` and test.  Also grab that whole log line with `service httpd status -l`

Comment: Still not working with setenforce 0 and updated the post

Comment: Ok, looks like it might actually be running.  What happens when you run `puppet agent --test` on an agent?

Comment: I refreshed iptable and SELinux and it works. But how to do I make this automatic from bootup?

Comment: Those settings should stick, can you determine which one is not holding its setting properly between boots?

Comment: SELinux is keep on going back to Enforce from Permissive.

Comment: Try setting `disabled` in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`?

Comment: Works for now. Do you want to create an answer so that I can vote to give you credit? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have "-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT" in iptables.

Once you connect, it will say "The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not ''" which is NOT an error.

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error show below steps bring Puppet Master back to life. Thanks to Shane Madden for guidance.

```
$ sudo service iptables restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  iptables.service
$ sudo service httpd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
$ sudo chkconfig httpd on
Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable httpd.service'.
$ sudo service httpd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
$ sudo setenforce permissive 
$ sudo sed -i 's\=enforcing\=permissive\g' /etc/sysconfig/selinux
$ sudo getenforce
```